# Passing ULONG *

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I'm dealing with the following function:

```
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Write( 
        /* [in] */ const void *pBuff,
        /* [in] */ ULONG cb,
        /* [out] */ ULONG *pcbWritten) = 0;
```

Previously, I have used it like this, and it worked:

```
hr = pOutputSite->Write((short*)&nShortsFromFloats[0], (iSizeShorts * 2), NULL);
```

I didn't use the last parameter, but everything else worked fine.

Now I wanted to the use the last parameter, and I tried the following:

```
ULONG lWritten = 0;

hr = pOutputSite->Write((short*)&nShortsFromFloats[0], (iSizeShorts * 2), (ULONG*)lWritten);
```

lWritten however stays 0, so I guess it didn't work.

How would the last parameter be passed correctly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pointer to a variable is obtained with the address-of operator `&`, not by casting to a pointer type.

Your cast causes undefined behavior, because the cast effectively does a `reinterpret_cast` from integral to pointer type. The result of that may not be dereferenced (which you are probably doing in `Write` though).

In general, you should almost always avoid C style casts as you are using. They can do all sorts of dangerous casts without warning, such as this one leading to undefined behavior.

For example `(short*)` shouldn't be there either. The pointer is cast to `const void*` implicitly anyway, so at best it is redundant. Worst case it causes undefined behavior as above, as well.

If you get any error messages without explicit casts, then most likely it means that you are doing something wrong and adding an explicit cast will probably just suppress the error message without actually fixing the problem. You need to carefully consider each explicit cast that you use and prefer `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` and/or `const_cast` where applicable (the latter two in particular require special care to be taken). These casts are limited in what types they will cast and sometime also have different semantics, making it less likely to do problematic casts.

```
hr = pOutputSite->Write(&nShortsFromFloats[0], (iSizeShorts * 2), &lWritten);
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation about the (short*) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `&lWritten` instead. `&` is the address-of operator which gets you a pointer to a value.

Comment: Is this correct?  ULONG lWritten = 0;

 hr = pOutputSite->Write((short*)&nShortsFromFloats[0], (iSizeShorts * 2), &lWritten);